# applet reloading using java script

Tags: javascript, security, applet

problem statement : to reload the applet without reloading the browser context

approch taken :

1. i thought probably javascript will not be able to invoke lifecycle methods of the applet so instead of calling start method of the applet lifecycle from the javascript i create my own mystart method where i am doing my applet stuff and tried calling mystart method in javascript ...it didnot help and is throwing security access voilation in that case as well .
2. I have one more method with name setdieseasename in my applet which i am able to call from my javascript .

my javascript :

```
function showSelected(value){
alert("i am in the javascript code atleast ");  
var applet =document.getElementById('decisiontreeapplet');
alert("i am adding before the myinit call");
applet.setDieasename(value);
alert("i am adding after the myinit call");
applet.myStart();
alert("i am here after calling mystart method");
}
```

applet code :
package com.vaannila.utility;

```
//import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;



import prefuse.util.ui.JPrefuseApplet;

public class dynamicTreeApplet extends JPrefuseApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int i = 1;
    public static String dieasenameencode="Malaria";




    public void init() {

     }



    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        myStart();
    }
    public void myStart() {
        System.out.println(" i am in the mystart method 111111111111");
        URL url = null;
        String dencode=null;
        String dieasename=null;

        if (dieasenameencode!=null){
        dencode = dieasenameencode.trim();
        System.out.println("the codebase to check if dencode is null method 2222222222222222222  ");
        }
        try {
            if(dencode!=null){ 
            System.out.println("the codebase to check if dencode is null method 3333333333333333  ");   
            dieasename = URLEncoder.encode(dencode, "UTF-8");
            }
            System.out.println(" i am just before the url connection code 444444444444444444");
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/docRuleToolProtocol/refreshAction.do?disease_name="+dieasename);
            System.out.println("i am after url connection 55555555555555555555");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            System.out.println(" i am here after creating a open connection 666666666666666");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            InputStream ois = con.getInputStream();
            this.setContentPane(dynamicView.demo(ois, "name"));
            ois.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            f.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
        ++i;
        }
    public void setDieasename(String message){



        System.out.println("atleast i am here and call is made ");
        dieasenameencode=message;

        myStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"problem statement : to reload the applet without reloading the browser context"*  No, it seems the problem is ever having to refresh the applet by reloading it.  Add a button to the applet that refreshes it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to refresh your applet with JS only you can
create a JS function (lets say) A which invokes applet Java method B (and make method B refresh your applet UI); 
java **netscape.javascript** lib can help you with this task because it provides Java applet and JS interaction possible
for more information you can read [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch22_02.htm) and [this docs](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html)

Good luck